# Python: Why can't my program write to a file from a list?

Tags: python

I have a txt file of clues e.g. A is #,  B is ?, C is @ etc.

I'm trying to read a ciphertxt file and swap the cipher-symbol using my txt file of clues above which I have imported into a list.

For some reason, it won't perform my substitution as expected.

```
def Import_Clues_to_Lists():
global letter_list
global symbol_list
file_clues=open('clues.txt','r')
for line in file_clues:
    for character in line:
        if character.isalpha() == True:
            letter_list[int(ord(character)-65)]  = line[0]
            symbol_list[int(ord(character)-65)] = line[1]
file_clues.close()


def Perform_Substitution():
Import_Clues_to_Lists()
print(letter_list)
print(symbol_list)
file_words = open('words.txt','r')
temp_words = open('wordsTEMP.txt','w')
for line in file_words:
    for character in line:
        if character.isalpha() == False:
            position = symbol_list.index(character) # get the position for the list
            equivalent_letter = letter_list[position] # get the equivalent letter
            temp_words.write(equivalent_letter) # substitute the symbol for the letter in the temp words file.
        else:
            temp_words.write(character)
file_words.close()
temp_words.close()
import os # for renaming files
#os.remove('words.txt')
#os.rename('wordsTEMP.txt','words.txt')
menu()
```

Any ideas where my logic has gone wrong?

Comment: What *do* you get? No file? Empty file? File with surprising contents? Try separating input (`file` > `str`), encryption (`str` > `str`), and output (`str`> `file`) so you can test each component in isolation.

Comment: The ciphertext file (words.txt) remains unchanged. No substitutions made. Can't figure out why...

Comment: You open it in `r`(ead-only) mode and have commented out the switch with the temporary file...

Comment: first of all, do not use globals for such a simple task. make it so `Import_clues_to_list()` actually return a list (or a tuple of lists), and give those lists to `Perform_Substitution()`. And then write two hundred times "[**globals are evil**](http://m0g.net/stuff/globals_are_evil.jpeg)"

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your functions.

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of clues.txt?

Comment: As @jonrsharpe indicated, you need to provide additional information regarding how or in what way it's "not working".

Comment: Really like the use of dictionaries!! BUT...am still encountering problem with swapping a Value for a KEy in the dictionary. Remember, i am reading an external file...which is full of symbols...and these symbols should be 'values' in my dictionary. I want to substitute these symbols (or 'dictionary values') for letters ( dictionary 'keys')... as i have set up my dictionary in the form dictionary = {'A':'#','B':'£','C':'&','D':'&'} etc WHAT AM I MISSING?

Answer (score 1):

It might be better if you use a dictionary to hold your symbols and the characters they represent - a *substitution* dictionary.  It will make your code more readable which might make it easier to find the problem.

If `clues.txt` looks something like this:

```
a!
b#
c$
d%
```

Try these out:

```
def Import_Clues_to_Lists():
    '''Create a substitution dictionary

    returns dict, {symbol : character}
    '''
    sub = dict()
    with open('clues.txt','r') as file_clues:
        for line in file_clues:
            # symbol = line[1], letter = line[0]
            sub[line[1]] = line[0]
    return sub

def Perform_Substitution():
    '''Iterate over characters of a file and substitute letters for symbols.

    creates a new file --> wordsTEMP.txt

    returns None
    '''
    # substitute is a dictionary of {symbol : character} pairs
    substitute = Import_Clues_to_Lists()
    for sym, char in substitute.items(): print(sym, char)
    with open('words.txt','r') as file_words, open('wordsTEMP.txt','w') as temp_words:
        for line in file_words:
            for character in line:
                if character in substitute:
                    character = substitute[character]
                temp_words.write(character)
```

Comment: Really like the use of dictionaries!! BUT...am still encountering problem with swapping a Value for a KEy in the dictionary.  Remember, i am reading an external file...which is full of symbols...and these symbols should be 'values' in my dictionary. I want to substitute these symbols (or 'dictionary values') for letters ( dictionary 'keys')... as i have set up my dictionary in the form   dictionary = {'A':'#','B':'£','C':'&','D':'&'} etc    WHAT AM I MISSING?

Comment: Your 'clues' file is a set of key:value pairs, where the key is the symbol that will be in the cyphertext, and the value is what the actual output letter should be. As your question is worded, this answer should solve it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, that work thing really interferes with playtime... You might be missing the fact that your solution will be made easier if you set up your dictionary with symbols as the keys and the letters they represent as the values - like I did above. If you cannot change the way your **initial** dictionary is set up, you can create a temporary dictionary with the key:value pairs swapped with the following: ```temp_dict = {v:k for k, v in my_dict.items()}```.